# Home wired network not responding to switch

Tags: networking, ethernet, home-networking, switch

I have an issue with a house I recently remodeled. I wired the whole house, through a contractor, with cat6 cables with my modem, Motorola Surfboard, and router, Asus RT-AC66R in the closet upstairs. I have 4 rooms cabled from that closet with one room being in the basement.

The problems come from when I tried to use the lan on my computer in the basement as well as when I hooked the basement lan port to a switch. When I wire my computer it does not immediately assign an IP address to the computer and doesnt recognize that an ethernet port is plugged in at all. I have to go to network and sharing center on windows 10 and troubleshoot problems. This often occurs "Resetting ethernet switch..." then half the time it resolves and assigns an IP address and then I can proceed with using the internet and half the time it will not detect an ethernet chord is plugged in or say that there is no IP address.

The second problem is I am trying to use a switch in the basement,TP link TL-SF1005D, to have two computers working off lan at the same time and the chord from the ethernet port in the wall to the switch does not recognize there is a chord plugged in. I have plugged the switch directly into the router upstairs and it works fine. I have also tested in all of the other rooms as well and there is no light for the port where it is plugged in.

My main concern is that the wiring was not done correctly but I am not sure if this is a router setting or something along those lines either that is not communicating when i create a two ethernet chord link router_female>Male_cat6 upstairs>female cat6 room port>male ethernet chord>female_computer.

Any help or suggestions of how to check anything or try solutions are more than welcome! Thanks!

Comment: "I wired the whole house, through a contractor" -- Start at layer 1; test your wiring before continuing debugging.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Does that mean I should buy something like this? https://www.amazon.com/Tonor-RJ45-Network-Cable-Tester/dp/B00OUFX38W/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1477146861&sr=8-1&keywords=ethernet+cable+tester

Comment: ya. you cant trust anything until you trust the cables.

Comment: Awesome. I will try that out and report back!

Comment: Maybe call that contractor back and have them complete their work.